# How to update text in matplotlib with serial data from Arduino?

Tags: matplotlib, arduino, pyserial, colormap

I am attempting to create an animated plot that updates in real time with the data from my serial port. Data is streamed in by an Arduino in an 8x8 array. The data are temperatures from an IR camera. I am able to create an instance of a figure but I cannot get the text to update with the serial stream data.

I tried to set 'plt.show(block=False)' so that the script would continue, but this makes the figure empty completely and scales it into a small window with a loading cursor that just continues to load.

I only want the text to update with the array data, as well as the colors from the new normalized data.

How can I get the text to update with the serial data in matplotlib?

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import serial
import time

tempdata = serial.Serial("COM3",9600)
tempdata.timeout = 100
strn = []

rows = ["A", "B", "C", "D",
              "E", "F", "G","H"]
columns = ["1", "2", "3", "4",
              "5", "6", "7","8"]

print("AMG8833 8x8 Infrared Camera")
time.sleep(0.75)
print("Connected to: " + tempdata.portstr)
time.sleep(0.75)
print("Initializing Camera...")

tempsArray = np.empty((8,8))

while True: #Makes a continuous loop to read values from Arduino

    fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
    im = ax.imshow(tempsArray,cmap='plasma')
    tempdata.flush()
    strn = tempdata.read_until(']') #reads the value from the serial port as a string
    tempsString = np.asarray(strn)
    tempsFloat = np.fromstring(tempsString, dtype=float, sep= ', ')

     # Axes ticks
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(columns)))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(rows)))
    # Axes labels
    ax.set_xticklabels(columns)
    ax.set_yticklabels(rows)
    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
                     rotation_mode="anchor")

    tempsArray.flat=tempsFloat  
    im.set_array(tempsArray)

    ax.set_title("")
    fig.tight_layout()
    #Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        for j in range(len(columns)):
            text = ax.text(j, i, tempsArray[i, j],
                                ha="center", va="center", color="w")

    plt.show()
```

[Heat Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeAMT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dynamic updating can be achieved with matplotlib's [interactive mode](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode). The answer to your question is very similar to [this one](http://matplotlib%20interacive%20mpde): basically you need to enable interactive mode with `ion()` and then update the plot **without** calling the `show()` (or correlated) function.
Also, the plot and subplots are to be created only once, before the input loop.

This is the modified example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import serial
import time

tempdata = serial.Serial("COM3",9600)
tempdata.timeout = 100
strn = []

rows = ["A", "B", "C", "D",
              "E", "F", "G","H"]
columns = ["1", "2", "3", "4",
              "5", "6", "7","8"]

print("AMG8833 8x8 Infrared Camera")
time.sleep(0.75)
print("Connected to: " + tempdata.portstr)
time.sleep(0.75)
print("Initializing Camera...")

tempsArray = np.empty((8,8))

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# The subplot colors do not change after the first time
# if initialized with an empty matrix
im = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(8,8),cmap='plasma')

# Axes ticks
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(columns)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(rows)))
# Axes labels
ax.set_xticklabels(columns)
ax.set_yticklabels(rows)
# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
                 rotation_mode="anchor")

ax.set_title("")
fig.tight_layout()

text = []

while True: #Makes a continuous loop to read values from Arduino

    tempdata.flush()
    strn = tempdata.read_until(']') #reads the value from the serial port as a string
    tempsString = np.asarray(strn)
    tempsFloat = np.fromstring(tempsString, dtype=float, sep= ', ')

    tempsArray.flat=tempsFloat  
    im.set_array(tempsArray)

    #Delete previous annotations
    for ann in text:
        ann.remove()
    text = []

    #Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    for i in range(len(rows)):
        for j in range(len(columns)):
            text.append(ax.text(j, i, tempsArray[i, j],
                                ha="center", va="center", color="w"))

    # allow some delay to render the image
    plt.pause(0.1)

plt.ioff()
```

**Note**: this code worked for me, but since I don't have an Arduino right now I tested it with a randomly generated sequence of frames (`np.random.rand(8,8,10)`), so I might have overlooked some detail. Let me know how it works.

Comment: How can I get the colors to normalize with respect to each frame and not the value history since initialization?

Comment: The camera likes to throw "-1" randomly within frames all across the array which destroys the normalization. What would you recommend to get around this and display the colors within a normal temp range (20-40 *C). I attempted to set vmax and vmin but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to not normalize -1 values, maybe setting them to 0?